# Should I always stash my changes before committing in Smartgit?

Tags: git, smartgit

Suppose I made changes in 7 files and I want to commit 3 files of them, so should I have to stash the other 4 files or not for successful commit? I am new to smartgit and most of the times fumble and get errors while committing my changes, so I figured maybe this is the cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you aren't changing branches, you don't have to stash.
While committing, just commit/select only those 3 files you have to commit.
Then Push these files upstream. Your remaining 4 files will stay intact without getting committed or pushed.

Comment: You can also stage/commit only some changes in a file using the Index Editor instead of commit the hole file...